# disable hindi characters in input type text

Tags: html, validation

i am tyring to disable hindi characters in the input form because those characters are not disaplyed properly in my pdf document.

i tried using this

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="User Name*" maxlength="30" onkeypress="return /[a-zA-Z ]/i.test(event.key)" required>
```

above input fied allows A to Z characters and Space ( ) on the desktop and works as expected, but if i try with the mobile device and try input using google indic keyboard, it allows hindi character also which i don't want to allow.

Answer (score 1):

according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress), the key press event is deprecated and not supported in chrome mobile. Try the `onkeyup`-event for mobile.

Comment: I tried using onkeyup as suggested by you but then it does not work on the desktop chrome, I did not try it on a mobile device because I need this to work on mobile as well as on desktop.

Comment: Then just use `onkeyup` on mobile and `onkeypress` on desktop, where is the problem?